# Get marker on the user's current location on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I m working with google map. I want to get marker pointed to the current location of user by default.How can i do this.Here is my code and is there any way to get the map of India only on google map.plz help me..

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_activity1);
    MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    final GoogleMap map = fm.getMap();
    if(map!=null){
         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


        if(map!=null){
            Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();

            if(myLocation !=null){
            LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
                    myLocation.getLongitude());


            CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
           }
        }
    // Setting a click event handler for the map
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            map.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            double lat=latLng.latitude;
            double longitude=latLng.longitude;
            String LAT=String.valueOf(lat);
            String LONGITUDE=String.valueOf(longitude);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LocationActivity.class);
            // Sending lat/long to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, LAT);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LONG, LONGITUDE);
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get marker pointed to the current location, you can do like that:

```
    Location myLcation = map.getMyLocation();

    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(myLcation.getLatitude(),myLcation.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions currentLocationMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(myPosition)
                .title(/*YOUR TITLE*/)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable./*YOUR ICON*/));

    map.addMarker(currentLocationMarker);
```

if you want to zoom on this position:

```
   CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 6);
   mMap.animateCamera(location);
```

Comment: I have edited my question...It is showing me the error...I have posted the logcat also..plz help me..

Comment: did you add *map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);* after map instantiation?

Comment: Yes, i have added it..and it is working..thank you so much...But when i have added the CameraUpdate it is not working...and marker is also not set on current location...

Comment: It should work, check your code maybe you have something wrong!

Comment: only zoom is not working..if i place CameraUpdate function after initialize the map..it is showing me the error..

Comment: I have edited my code...It is showing me the current location on map...But it is not zooming on that current location

Comment: i think the zoom depends on location, try to zoom x10(or 6) instead of 17... otherwise post your error log

Comment: did you decrease the zoom level? try to use my code with *CameraUpdate* .

Comment: Yes, I have try this..For Location class,It is giving me the null pointer exception error...Is there any permission i have to add in manifest file for using location class???

Comment: yes i have added all these permissions but still it is giving me null pointer exception

Comment: are you sure that your location is not null? wifi activated? which line cause the eception?

Comment: yes..If i am removing this line  if(myLocation !=null) then it is giving me null pointer exception error...And if i m not removing it it is not zooming on current location...

Comment: so your map.getMyLocation(); return always null object, are you using google map api v2 or v3?